# A doubt about "infinitely often" and $\limsup$ of a sequence (Example of Kai Lai Chung page: 119) without zero-one laws

Tags: probability-theory, limsup-and-liminf, law-of-large-numbers

I was reading an example of Chung's book "A course in probability theory" 3rd edition. The example says:

Let $\{X_n\}$ be independent random variables with common distribution function $F$ such that
$$\mathbb{P}\left(X_1=n\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(X_1=-n\right)=\frac{c}{n^2\log n}$$
where c is the constant
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2\log n}\right)^{-1}$$
If $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$, the idea in this example is to show that
$$\limsup\frac{S_n}{n}=+\infty \quad \text{and} \quad \liminf\frac{S_n}{n}=-\infty$$

I understand all of the arguments given by Chung, except the last step. In some point, we can show that
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{|S_n|}{n}>\frac{A}{2} \ \text{i.o.}\right)=1 \quad \quad \quad (1)$$

With this in hand, it follows that
\begin{equation}
\limsup\frac{|S_n|}{n}\ge \frac{A}{2} \quad \text{a.s.} \quad \quad \quad (2)
\end{equation}
but Chung says that  from (1) follows
$$\limsup \frac{S_n}{n}\ge \frac{A}{2}$$

So, my question is: why he can drop the absolute value?. I tried to work with (1) in order to arrive to the conclusion given by Chung, writing it in terms of set, using the definition of $\limsup$ for sets and nothing. Moreover, how can I arrive to the conclusion given by Chung without zero one laws?

My question arises in a more general setting, because I've seen that proving
$$\limsup \bigg|\frac{S_n}{a_n}\bigg|=1 \quad \text{a.s.}$$
implies
$$\limsup \frac{S_n}{a_n}=1=-\liminf \frac{S_n}{a_n}$$
where $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence of no-negative numbers. For example, the law of iterated logarithm .

I appreciate you help.

Answer (score 1):

$\lim \sup \frac {S_n} n$ is measuarble w.r.t. the tail sigma algebra which makes it a.s constant. Similarly, $\lim \inf \frac {S_n} n$ is constant a.s. and $\frac {S_n} n$ is  symmetric by independence an symmetry of each $X_n$. It follows that if $\lim \sup \frac {S_n} n=c$ a.s  then $\lim \inf \frac {S_n} n=-c$ a.s and $\lim \sup \frac {|S_n|} n=|c|$ a.s.

The arguemnt for the last statement in your question is the same but $a_n \to \infty$ is esential.

Comment: @KeviRamaMurthy I see! I also thought in tail events, but I didn't see how to use them. So the important facts here are symmetry and independence, but how can I conclude that $\limsup S_n/n \ge A/2$ using (1)?

Comment: @UrielHerrera That seems to be a mistake (or a typo). But $\lim \sup$ of $|S_n| n =\infty$ a.s. and this implies $\lim \sup S_n /s =\infty $ a.s., so the final conclusion holds.

Comment: @KeviRamaMurthy I also think it is a typo. Thanks for your help :D

Comment: I was wondering if $\pm \infty$ should be treated as constants in this setting?

Comment: @UrielHerrera Yes. If a sigma algebra is trivial (in the sense every set in it has probbaility $0$ or $1$) and if $X$ is an extended real valued function measuarble w.r.t this sigma algebra then $X$ is  a constant a.e. and the constant can be $\pm \infty$.